# Is there any way to change one spark DF's datatype to match with other DF's datatype

Tags: pyspark

I have one spark DF1 with datatype,

```
string (nullable = true)
integer (nullable = true)
timestamp (nullable = true)
```

And one more spark DF2 (which I created from Pandas DF)

```
object
 int64
object
```

Now I need to change the DF2 datatype to match with the Df1 datatype. Is there any common way to do that. Because every time I may get different columns and different datatypes.
Is there any way like assign the DF1 data type to some structType and use that for DF2?

Comment: `object` is not a spark data type -- see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/data_types.html#data-types) for all spark data types

Comment: Yes, "object" is pandas datatype, which is converted as string in spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose you have 2 dataframes - `data1_sdf` and `data2_sdf`. you can use a dataframe's schema to extract the column's data type by `data_sdf.select('column_name').schema[0].dataType`.

here's an example where `data2_sdf` columns are casted using `data1_sdf` within a `select`

```py
data2_sdf. \
    select(*[func.col(c).cast(data1_sdf.select(c).schema[0].dataType) if c in data1_sdf.columns else c for c in data_sdf.columns])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that your first object is a string-like column and your third object is timestamp-like column, you can try to use this method:

```
 df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
        df2.rdd, schema=df1.schema
    )
```

However, this method is not guaranteed, some cases are not valid (eg transform from string to integer). Also, this method might not be good in performance perspective. Therefore, you better use `cast` to change the data type of each column.

Comment: do `df2.select(*df1.columns).rdd` to make sure the column positions are same